# 1 to many with status check on many side

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to this sql world. After I'm a developer with limited knowledge in SQL & simple joins. I have an issue in writing sql join for one-to-many relationship. Here's my problem say -

For instance if I have a Customer table with:

```
id   Name         address
1    manoj        Japan
2    Sunil        US
```

And a Tickets table with:

```
id   customerid     ticketstatus
1    1               closed
2    1               closed
3    2               closed
4    1               open
5    2               closed
```

Now what I want after join is :

```
id        customername     ticketstatus
2         sunil            closed
```

So I want only those customer who's all tickets status has been closed.

Can any one help in writing join for this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT id,
       Name
FROM Customer
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT customerid
                  FROM Tickets
                  WHERE ticketstatus <> 'closed'
                );
```

This statement lists the `Customer`'s `id` and `name` where their `id` does not appear in a list of `customerid`'s (from the `Tickets` table) that correspond to a status other than `closed`.

No joining is necessary, unless you wish to show the `ticketstatus` even though it will always be `closed`.  In that case, please try the following...

```
SELECT Customer.id AS id,
       Name,
       ticketstatus
FROM Customer
JOIN Tickets ON Customer.id = Tickets.customerid
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT customerid
                  FROM Tickets
                  WHERE ticketstatus <> 'closed'
                )
GROUP BY Customer.id;
```

Please note the extra field to be included in the output and the `JOIN` that is performed.  As multiple instances of the selected fields are possible owing to the Customer potentially having more than one `closed` `Ticket`, I have also added a `GROUP BY Customer.id` clause to reduce the output to just one record for each `Customer`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: This will get customers who don't have any tickets at all.

Comment: "No joining is necessary" isn't quite right, since a NOT IN condition is a form of join (specifically an ANTI-JOIN). This form is, indeed, less expensive than a "standard" join though. Then: the NOT IN condition is fine if the status can never be NULL; if it can be NULL, then more care must be taken.

Comment: mathguy, Thank you for the interesting comment on (`NOT`) `IN` and various types of joins.  I've never really thought of it that way.  Also, I agree with your comment about potential `NULL` troubles, though in this case I have assumed that `customerid` will never have any `NULL` values.

Comment: Answer expanded to include statements appropriate to situations where the Questioner does and does not wish to display the `ticketstatus` field (which will always be `closed`).

Answer (score 1):

Standard aggregate (sub)query on the Tickets table, followed by a join to get the customer name:

```
with
     customer ( id, name, address ) as (
       select 1, 'Manoj', 'Japan' from dual union all
       select 2, 'Sunil', 'US'    from dual
     ),
     tickets ( id, customerid, ticketstatus ) as (
       select 1, 1, 'closed' from dual union all
       select 2, 1, 'closed' from dual union all
       select 3, 2, 'closed' from dual union all
       select 4, 1, 'open'   from dual union all
       select 5, 2, 'closed' from dual
     )
-- END of test data (not part of the solution!)
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select s.id, c.name, 'closed' as ticketstatus
from   (
         select   customerid as id
         from     tickets
         group by customerid
         having   min(ticketstatus) = 'closed'
            and   max(ticketstatus) = 'closed'
       ) s
       join customer c
       on s.id = c.id
;

ID  NAME   TICKETSTATUS
--  -----  ------------
 2  Sunil  closed
```

This assumes the `ticketstatus` can't be `NULL` - otherwise some care must be taken, since `min()` and `max()` ignore nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
        Select distinct a.ID, a.Name as customername, b.ticketstatus
            from
            Customer a
            inner join
            Tickets b
            on a.Id=b.CustomerId
            where a.Id not in
           (select CustomerId from 
            Tickets where ticketstatus <> 'closed'
           ) 
           and b.ticketstatus='closed'
            ;

    OR

   //With Same logic and different approach

    Select distinct a.ID, a.Name as customername, b.ticketstatus
        from
        Customer a

        inner join

       (select CusotomerID,ticketstatus from Tickets 
        where ticketstatus='closed'
       ) b

        on a.Id=b.CustomerId
        where a.Id not in
       (select CustomerId from 
        Tickets where ticketstatus <> 'closed'
       ) ;
```

Comment: This will get all customers who have closed tickets, but will also return those with closed tickets who have open tickets.

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: This will return an incorrect results set if a third `ticketstatus` exists or is ever introduced.  As the Question is specifically asking for only those Customers who have all their `ticketstatus` values set to `closed`, you can make your statement more robust by changing `where ticketstatus='open'` to `where ticketstatus <> 'closed'`.

Comment: Is showing `T.Ticketstatus` called for? We know that it will always be closed.

Comment: Thanks. Yup, showing ticket status does not make sense as it isalways closed. But that's the requirement in the output. Anyways, no harm in putting it over there in output if that's what is required.

Comment: Dang.  Missed that part of the Question.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: You and `xQbert` make a good point.  I have adapted my Answer accordingly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to find all users who have at least one ticket and who have no tickets that are not closed:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name AS customername
  FROM customers c
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tickets t
                 WHERE t.customerid = c.id )
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tickets t
                     WHERE t.customerid = c.id
                       AND t.ticketstatus != 'closed' );
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd join customer and tickets to define the result set needed.
I'd then exclude all customers having tickets that are not closed.
I used coalesce on ticketstatus in case any value could be null.

```
SELECT Distinct C.ID, C.Name as CustomerName, T.TicketStatus
FROM Customer C
INNER JOIN Tickets T
 on C.ID = T.customerID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM TICKETS T2
                  WHERE coalesce(TicketStatus,'NULL') <> 'closed'
                  and T2.CustomerID = T.CustomerID)
```

Comment: Is showing `T.Ticketstatus` called for?  We know that it will always be `closed`.

Comment: That's a question to ask the originator of the question.  It's in their expected results; so it's in my answer.  Technically I could avoid the join to Tickets and hardcode 'closed' to get a gain in performance...  but *shrug*  if they change to show open then I'd have to change two places instead of one.

Comment: You and `India.Rocket` make a good point.  I have adapted my Answer accordingly.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for something like this:

```
select distinct a.customername, b.ticketstatus from table1 a
join table2 b on a.id = b.customerid 
where b.ticketstatus = 'closed'
```

Comment: This will get all customers who have at least one 'closed' status - not what the OP requested.

Comment: This will return all Customers who have at least one `Ticket` with a `ticketstatus` of `closed`, including those who have another `Ticket` with a `ticketstatus` of `open` (or any other potential `ticketstatus` value).

Comment: Is showing `b.ticketstatus` called for? We know that it will always be closed.  Also, I recommend also showing the `a.id` field (unless specifically asked to do otherwise) as a way of differentiating between duplicated names.  e.g. How will you handle two `John Smith`'s?  Finally, `a.customername` should read `a.Name`, as per the Question's table definition.  You can change `a.customername` to `a.Name AS customername` to show the different name in the output.

Comment: Never mind about the `ticketstatus` - `xQbert` and `India.Rocket` have set me right on that one and I have adapted my Answer accordingly.